# Search builder fails In Group and Not In Group Search

Tags: search, search-builder, searchkit

This was run on your demo account using Search Builder. All the records selected are in both groups.
8 Contacts
Group(s) **In** Advisory Board ...AND...
Group Status 'Added' ...AND...
Group(s) **Not In** Newsletter Subscribers ...AND...
Group Status 'Added'
Select Records:  All 8 records    0 Selected records only

Comment: more of a sidestep than an answer, but in case you don't know of its existence - under Search > Custom search, and there is an include/exclude which works for groups or tags https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/custom?csid=4&reset=1

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE.  I can reproduce that and it seems to be a bug so have logged it as an [issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2997).  However, I'd suggest you look at Search Kit rather than Search Builder. See [this](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contact?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22id%22,%22display_name%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5B%22groups:name%22,%22IN%22,%5B%22Advisory%20Board%22%5D%5D,%5B%22groups:name%22,%22NOT%20IN%22,%5B%22Newsletter%20Subscribers%22%5D%5D%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D)

[image]

One of the many nice things about Search Kit is that you can expand the Query Info section to see how your GUI entry is being interpreted.  Search Builder doesn't give you any info to help figure out why it's not showing the results you expect.